# DB Table listening in Hibernate, Spring

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I am new to web development using Spring , Hibernate. Now i need to write a listener , which can listen to any update/delete on DB tables. 
In simple java , i use trigger to invoke the api , but no idea in hibernate. Kindly help

Comment: Very few databases (only some embedded ones, AFAIK) allow arbitrary Java code from your application to be called when a value is changed. You should change your design, or use stored procedures. Oh, and it's called *Hibernate*, not *Hibernet*.

Comment: You might use hibernate interceptors and events(It can monitor changes made by hibernate, outside changes cannot be monitored. http://dunithd.wordpress.com/2009/10/27/create-database-triggers-like-features-using-hibernate-events/

Comment: I need to add listener to a particular DB table. I referred this  http://dunithd.wordpress.com/2009/10/27/create-database-triggers-like-features-using-hibernate-events/ , but it is listening to all events then if that event is instance of particular entity , it is doing the action. I dont want to listen every event , but want to create a particular listener for particular table (entity) in model. We are following the mvc  model

Comment: The Hibernate documentation clearly explains how to write listeners. Give it a try and if you encounter a difficulty, provide code excerpt and error description.